# How to split string by delimeter and multiple group by and count them in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LogData List and which is designed like below.

```
public class LogDataEntity
{
   public string IndexPattern;
   public int Type;
   public LogDataEntity(string pattern , int type)
   {
         IndexPattern = pattern;
         Type = type;
   }
}


List<LogDataEntity> list = new List<LogDataEntity>();
list.add(new LogDataEntity("1,2,9,10", 2));    
list.add(new LogDataEntity("1,10", 1));
list.add(new LogDataEntity("1,2,3", 2));
list.add(new LogDataEntity("3,9,10", 3));
list.add(new LogDataEntity("9,10", 2));
list.add(new LogDataEntity("9,10", 2));
```

And i want the result like below.

```
 [Index]   [Type]    [Count]
   10    :   2          3      
   9     :   2          3     
   1     :   2          2      
   3     :   1          2     
   2     :   2          2 
   3     :   3          1
   9     :   3          1
   10    :   3          1
   1     :   1          1
```

I want to group by and count not only splited string(indexpattern) but also
type too. And i want to count and show them by OrderByDescending(Count).

I think There is multiple group by.
How should i do this with Linq?

Comment: actually you question is almost perfect, you have a copy paste example with a minimal program to reproduce the problem, sample input and expected output. I guess the only thing missing to receive a couple of upvotes is an attempt of your own. Where you show that you have at least tried anything to solve it on your own. I would vote up ;)

Comment: oh.. i'm sorry , and i got a hint for below 2 people and i already self answered my complete linq code to this question.

Comment: " i'm sorry" you don't need to be sorry. It was just a suggestion as how to improve the quality of your question. " i already self answered my complete linq code" good for you. But that does not influece the quality of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to create list of (Index, Type) pairs, then group by and count to do the rest:

```
var pairs = data.SelectMany(x => x.IndexPattern
                                  .Split(",")
                                  .Select(y => new {Index = y, Type = x.Type});

var res = from p in pairs
          group p by new { p.Index, p.Type } into grp
          select new {
            Index = grp.Key.Index,
                    grp.Key.Type,
                    grp.Count()
          };
```

(An `order by` clause can be added before the final `Select` as required.)

Comment: Thanks for answering but i can not use grp.count() in there. may be it is not a function....

Comment: @summation [`Enumerable.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) certainly is a function, but without an exact error message it is very hard to tell what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for @Richard  and  Dmitry Bychenko to answering. I finally got a hint in this 2 answers.

below is my linq code.

Comment: var pairs = Logs.SelectMany(x => x.IndexPattern.Split(',').Select(y => new { Index = y, Type= x.Type }));

var pairs2 = (from p in pairs group p by p into grp select new { Index = grp.Key.Index, Reason = grp.Key.Type, Count = grp.Count() }
                ).OrderByDescending(p => p.Count);

Answer (score 3):

You've, probably, stuck in `SelectMany`; all the other commands are quite evident:

```
var result = list
  .SelectMany(record => record 
     .IndexPattern
     .Split(',')
     .Select(item => {
        index = item,
        type = record.Type, 
      }))
   .GroupBy(item => item)
   .OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Count())
   .Select(chunk => $"{chunk.index,-10} : {chunk.type,-10} {chunk.Count()}");  

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering~!

Answer (score 0):

This is improve version or previous answers.

```
var pairs = Logs.SelectMany(x => x.IndexPattern.Split(',').Select(y => new { 
Index = y, Type= x.Type }));

var pairs2 = (from p in pairs group p by p into grp select new { Index = 
grp.Key.Index, Reason = grp.Key.Type, Count = grp.Count() }
            ).OrderByDescending(p => p.Count);


foreach (var i  in pairs2) 
{

   //print with i
}
```